# text box format in Vc++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++

I am at the beginning of a steep learning curve with Vc++ (C++/CLI)

**How do you format text (numbers) in a text box on a form?**

`printf()` was easy, in the good old days ;-)

The following works but there are lots of decimal places.

I only need to display one decimal point.

that is **22.4**  not **22.4178301**

```
//Calculate the Power and current

fPower2 = (pow((fVoltagePkPk * 0.5 * 0.707),2) / 2);

fCurrent2 = fPower2 / (fVoltagePkPk * 0.5 * 0.707);



//Display the Power amd current in the text boxes

txtPower2->Text = Convert::ToString(fPower2);

txtCurrent2->Text = Convert::ToString(fCurrent2);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
fPower2.ToString("F1")
fCurrent2.ToString("F1")
```

The F1 refers to 1 fixed digit. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#Y2205 for more formatting options.

Comment: Brilliant 

Thank you

With each passing day i learn a little bit more, I need a good book on this C++/CLI stuff

Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Note as well if you wanted to control the rounding, you can use Math.Ceiling(), Math.Floor() and Math.Round(). eg. Math.Round(fPower2).ToString("F1")